# Should date and time have their own tables in this MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, database-performance

On any given day a blog could have several entries posted on it. As such I have two options (using MySQL and PHP):

- To give the entries table a date/timestamp column and repeat dates and times.
- To create three tables: entries, date and time and inner join them.

This may seem like an utterly barmy question, however I'm considering how much 'bloating' option A would cause in comparison to whether there is any performance gain/loss with that many inner joins?

**As an example:**

If 2 people posted at the same time every day, there would be 730 instances a year (732 on a leap year!) of that time in the database. Is that enough of a concern to warrant indexing and joining three tables?

Comment: Option A. Absolutely. Option B makes so sense.

Comment: You will have to have an index pointing to the other tables. Better put the date and time in the same table as the data it refers and belongs to.

Comment: @juergen d thank you. why? the times are non-unique in the example.

Comment: @KIKO Software. What makes it better? is it the indexing? Thank you

Comment: timestamps are long integers; even with an external table, you will still have to old a foreign key...  an integer. And the repetition would be the same.

Comment: This is basic refactoring. There are good books on this. Basically you should never make a seperate table to hold just one field, and then refer to it in a one to one relation from another table (or the other way around). It just doesn't make sense. It complicates your db schema and your SQL. Why do it?